# Google Calendar API - get events

Tags: php, mysql, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm using PHP and MySQL but I guess this question can be for almost anyone. I have a website where people can register/create an account and login. I have a calendar on my site for each user. I'm wanting to implement Google Calendar API (oauth) so they can login to their Google accounts and sync their Google Calendar events with the calendar on my site.

But through their documentation, I don't see anywhere that says how I can save the google account for each person on my site so that only their google account gets connected and that only their google calendar events go into their calendar on my site.

For example, if user 2 on my site links their google account (user2@gmail.com) through oauth, how does my site know next time it wants to get events from the google account to get it from user2@gmail.com and not another user's google account that have signed in? Here's what I'm trying to say:

```
user 2 = user2@gmail.com
user 5 = user5@gmail.com
user 8 = user8@gmail.com
```

so next time a user fetches events from Google calendar API, it will get it from their own google account and not another user's g account.

how should I go about doing this? Should I save something in my MySQL database?

Here is the full google calendar api v3 working code:

**link-google-account.php:**

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('client_secrets.json');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY);

if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);

  // Print the next 10 events on the user's calendar.
  $calendarId = 'primary';
  $optParams = array(
    'maxResults' => 10,
    'orderBy' => 'startTime',
    'singleEvents' => TRUE,
    'timeMin' => date('c'),
  );

  $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
  $results = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId, $optParams);

  if (count($results->getItems()) == 0) {
    print "No upcoming events found.\n";
  } else {
    print "Upcoming events:\n";
    foreach ($results->getItems() as $event) {
      $start = $event->start->dateTime;
      if (empty($start)) {
        $start = $event->start->date;
      }
      printf("%s (%s)\n", $event->getSummary(), $start);
    }
  }

} else {
  $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/oauth.php';
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
?>
```

**oauth.php:**

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfigFile('client_secrets.json');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/oauth.php');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY);

if (! isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
} else {
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
?>
```

Comment: Isn't this simply what sessions are for?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt what do you mean? like I already have sessions for user logins on my site but how can I associate the user id with the google calendar account?

Comment: How would you associate *anything* with a user? How do you know in who's user's context your code is running? Extending that to any additional data seems like a trivial exercise.

Comment: This is a non-issue I think. You're storing the google access token with the session of your current user. Once it expires, the user will be asked to log into google again, and another access token for that user will be provided. The user will never see a different user's session, so there's no concept of them using someone else's login. It's not your PHP server which logs into google, it's the individual user. You don't really need to do anything more to associate their account with your application as far as I can see.

Comment: If someone else goes onto your site at the same time, and hasn't logged into google, then there'll be no access token in their session and they'll have to log in themselves. I'm struggling to see what you're worried about really. Have you actually tried this scenario and encountered a problem with your application? It wouldn't be hard to simulate, all you need is two google accounts (which are free, of course) and two separate browser sessions.

Comment: @ADyson This was the thing I was looking for. What should my Google API code include so that the auth token will be stored and the user will never have reinitialize even if the user on my site logs out and logs back in?

Comment: if you set your access type to "offline" (it's an option you provide when you request the access token - check the documentation) then you can request a refresh token (the PHP client library may do that for you, I forget) which can be exchanged for a fresh access token once the previous one has expired. There is a limit to this I believe, and eventually the user will be asked to re-confirm their credentials.

Comment: Also I don't know exactly what process you mean when you say "reinitialise" (perhaps you can clarify?) but "even if the user logs out" makes no sense to me - if the user logs out of their google account, then you can't just carry out accessing their account on their behalf, they have to log in again first before they can do anything. The process of logging in again generates a new access token. Are you really talking about associating a particular google account with data held in your application?